# PHP defining namespaces on composer's vendor packages

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I'm having some issues with namespaces in PHP.

I've got everything nailed down and working within my project which is all running great. I used composer's autoload features to autoload all my project classes.

Recently I've needed to pull in a dependency through composer for securimage (captcha application). The problem I've got is that it won't work until I go editing the files and insert the following at the top of each php script.:

```
<?php namespace vendor\dapphp\securimage;
```

My composer.json file is using PSR-4 if that helps identify where I'm going wrong.

```
"psr-4": {
            "vendor\\dapphp\\securimage\\": "vendor/dapphp/securimage"
        }
```

My question in case it isn't obvious how do I pull in composer vendor projects and make PHP automatically insert/understand that these should be placed under the namespace

```
vendor\{userid}\{projectid}
```

without editing the actual files within.

I'm sure I've just missed something within the composer.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really missed anything. It's up to a package to namespace its source code. Unless the source code literally contains a `namespace` declaration, the code is in the global namespace. You cannot change that fact without changing all the involved source code. The Securimage code is not namespaced, period.

```
"psr-4": {
    "vendor\\dapphp\\securimage\\": "vendor/dapphp/securimage"
}
```

This merely configures the autoloader. Meaning, *should you try to load a class in the namespace `vendor\dapphp\securimage\...`*, Composer's autoloader knows where to find it. It does not place the code in this namespace.

Comment: Thanks for answering deceze. So what happens in the future when they decide to namespace their poject and I've got everything nailed down to addressing their classes in the global namespace?

Comment: Then you will have to update your code. :) Putting something into a namespace is basically the same as renaming everything or changing a function signature. It's bound to break backwards compatibility and there's no real way to avoid it.

Comment: I thought I was doing the right thing by using namespaces. I didn't expect to end up having a 3rd party hinder my own project. They really haven't done a good job with this namespace thing as it feels like a last minute hack.

I think I'll just fork the project and update their code so at least I've got some control over it. Many thanks, you've satisfied my question - thank you very much! :)

Comment: Or, you know, just use the third party library without namespaces. If everything else is namespaced, that's unlikely to ever be a problem. If they ever do update to use namespaces, you'll figure it out then. Better than having to maintain a fork and constantly include upstream patches.

Comment: I suppose the release first introducing namespaces will be released as a new major version because it breaks compatibility (changing namespaces and class names is an incompatible interface change). Expect either a new X+1.0.0 version, or maybe an entirely new package name.